# Inputting and Outputting Data from file in Vector Error?

Tags: c++

I am fairly new to C++ and I am not sure why my output file is blank.  I think it might have something to do with my functions? When I just put the code into main and not into a function, the output file will give me the information.. I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>

#define die(msg) {cerr << msg << endl; exit(1);}

using namespace std;

struct Eip
{
    string block;
    string blkSfx;
    string lot;
    string lotSfx;
};

void inputData(fstream &, vector<Eip>);
void outputData(fstream &, vector<Eip>);

int main()
{
    fstream fs("Book1.txt", ios::in);
    fstream fsout("SecuredEIP.txt", ios::out);

    if(!fs.is_open()) die("Can not open Book1.txt!");
    if(!fsout.is_open()) die("Can not open SecuredEIP.txt!");

    vector<Eip> name;

    inputData(fs, name);
    outputData(fsout, name);

    fs.close();
    fsout.close();
    return(0);
}

void inputData(fstream &fs, vector<Eip> name)
{
    while(fs) {
        Eip temp;
        getline(fs, temp.block, '\t');
        getline(fs, temp.blkSfx, '\t');
        getline(fs, temp.lot, '\t');
        getline(fs, temp.lotSfx, '\n');

        name.push_back(temp);
    }
}

void outputData(fstream &fsout, vector<Eip> name)
{
    for(int i = 1; i < name.size(); i++) {
        fsout << setw(4) << setfill('0');
        fsout << name[i].block;

        if(name[i].blkSfx == "")
            fsout << " ";
        else
            fsout << name[i].blkSfx;

        fsout << setw(3) << setfill('0');
        fsout << name[i].lot;

        if(name[i].lotSfx == "")
            fsout << "  " << endl;
        else
            fsout << name[i].lotSfx << " " << endl;
    }
}
```

Here is the data from my text file.

```
3965    1   
837     9   
3749    59  
3752    19  
3532    54  
6769    49  
535     10  
819     13  B
3616    84  
26      30  
3732    8   
3732    150 
6536    8   
71      2
```

Answer (score 1):

You are passing *copies* of your vector to `inputData`/`outputData` - make these references instead, i.e. change:

```
void inputData(fstream &fs, vector<Eip> name)
```

and

```
void outputData(fstream &fsout, vector<Eip> name)
```

to:

```
void inputData(fstream &fs, vector<Eip> &name)
```

and

```
void outputData(fstream &fsout, vector<Eip> &name)
```

Comment: OMG thanks for your help! The topic of passing by reference still confuses me. Orginally vector name is blank. Why would I still reference it?